# Who do @@OPTIONS and sp_configure provide different output?

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I right click on Server Name within “Object Explorer” and choose “Properties->Connections” I can see that nothing has been ticked in “Default Connection Options”. Also I can see when I ran `sp_configure 'user options'` (advanced options on) that config_value is 0. At the same time when I do "`SELECT @@OPTIONS`" I can see that value is 5496. It turns out to be true as enabled options are actually working.

The question is: why do I have misleading info in SMSS and sp_configure and why is it different from `@@OPTIONS` value despite [BOL saying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx)

> The bit positions in user options are identical to those in `@@OPTIONS`. Each connection has its own `@@OPTIONS` function, which represents the configuration environment. When logging in to Microsoft SQL Server, a user receives a default environment that assigns the current user options value to `@@OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["user options"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx) as a server level setting says (my bold)

> The user options option allows you to change the default values of the SET options (if the server's default settings are not appropriate). **A user can override these defaults by using the SET statement.**

Now, check the connection options in SSMS and then run SQL profiler. You'll note that SSMS (and other clients) issue a lot of SET commands that sets @@OPTIONS.

So *no* options are set at the server level (the zero you see). SSMS will set them for you, same as the SQLOLEDB, SQLNCLI, ODBC, DB-Lib etc drivers.

Example for [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx):

> The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver and SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider for SQL Server automatically set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to ON when connecting. This can be configured in ODBC data sources, in ODBC connection attributes, or OLE DB connection properties. The default for SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF for connections from DB-Library applications.

Comment: Yes, you are right. SQL Server Profiler -> Sessions ->Existing Connection shows clearly all SETs. Does the value changed by SET persist only for a duration of a current connection? If I open two tabs in SMSS it seems like I can change say QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and it won't affect server setting neither second session.

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov: If you change the SSMS defaults (via Tools..Options), it applies to new connections only. Running SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER will only affect that session. You can change it per connection too via the GUI menus (but don't have SQL Server installed to remember where it is sorry)

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answers.