# How to view default values of the SET options of a server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, configure

I read BOL but could not figure it out.

When i exec sp_configure it shows just 
[image]

Here I can not see if NOCOUNT or ANSI_WARNINGS are SET ON by befault.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the defaults here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190707.aspx

You can check your own settings using:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
```

And you can check any other session's settings using various columns in [sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "show advanced options" and run RECONFIGURE

The server defaults are all zero (nothing set) by the way. Your client or driver sets options automatically that will override any server defaults you set

See this for more: [Who do @@OPTIONS and sp_configure provide different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120625/who-do-options-and-sp-configure-provide-different-output/7122077#7122077)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that. But it works just for advanced options and doesn't affect user options.

Comment: All options are OFF as per my links and text at the server level